# Confused about relative url anchor tag

Tags: node.js, web, anchor, relative-path

I'm confused about relative href url in anchor tag. I have a case below:

I have a homepage that can be accessed with **abc.com/it** or **abc.com/it/index** with return the same page. In that page I have anchor tag with **relative url** href='./about' (I can not use absolute or root-relative url in this case). The problem is:

- When I access the page through url **abc.com/it/index**
  then click the anchor link, it will redirect to **abc.com/it/about**
  (this is my expected result).
- But if I access the page through **abc.com/it** then click the link, it
  will redirect to **abc.com/about** (this is not my expectation).

Anyone please give me a solution for this. Thank you all.

Comment: Are you having a folder named "it" with index file inside?

Comment: does index file is an HTML or js file?

Comment: I'm using ejs template with nodejs as server-side render, and use 2 route to return the same view page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to add a trailing slash to your base URL, i.e. `abc.com/it/`.

Here is the relevant line from the specification of relative URLs ([RFC 1808](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1808.txt))

> The last segment of the base URL's path (anything
>   following the rightmost slash "/", or the entire path if no
>   slash is present) is removed and the embedded URL's path is
>   appended in its place.

I would also suggest adding a redirect from `abc.com/it` to `abc.com/it/`

Comment: Thanks @Daniel, I will add a check and redirect to the url with trailing slash for sub-resource

Answer (score 1):

Thats because abc.com is your root directory.
Two options can solve this problem-

1. Change your root directory to abc.com/it
2. Change your url href-'./it/about

Comment: Hi @Rahul, change href will cause the 1st case redirect to abc.com/it/it/cntt :(

Comment: Try this- Just remove dot(.) from href='./it/about' and write href='/it/about'

Comment: Remove dot will make it a root-relative path it's not relative path, I also use some type like '../../it'